# Is it possible to disable zoom in lightningChartJS chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, zooming, lineseries, lightningchart

In a chart created using LightningChartJS one can zoom in or zoom out of a particular section by dragging the mouse.Is it possible to disable the zoom functionality?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please provide some more details so other users can get it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*ChartXY* has several methods for enabling/disabling individual mouse/touch interactions, all of which are named with the prefix: setMouseInteraction...

Zooming in can be disabled with

```
chart.setMouseInteractionRectangleZoom( false )
```

Fitting can be disabled with

```
chart.setMouseInteractionRectangleFit( false )
```